# Can't access $scope in dynamic $route AngularUI modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I've got an AngularJS test app that loads a modal window using AngularUI, dynamically, based on link path. My modal windows load, but no $scope variables in the modal controller are accessed by the template, and I can't trigger any $scope functions from the template.

[Here's a plunkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/OwDZV4Vbhbtd5TEX1E36/preview)

Here's the $routeProvider:

```
.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/page/:name', {
        templateUrl : 'modalContainer',
        controller : 'ModalCtrl'
    })
 })
```

and here's the controller:

```
.controller('ModalCtrl',['$scope', '$modal', '$route', function($scope, $modal, $route) {

    console.log("hello I am the ModalCtrl") //This console log runs

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl : 'modal.html',
    });

    $scope.activity = $route.current.pathParams.name;
    console.log($scope.activity) //This console log runs & shows the correct value,
                                 // but the $scope variable is not visible in the template

    //Modal controls
    $scope.close = function () {
        console.log("close!") //This does not run.
        modalInstance.close();
    };

}]);
```

I guess that I am creating the scope of the modal window incorrectly somehow, can someone see the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a controller for the modal window so that it can access the $scope, so the code would look like this:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl : 'modal.html',
    controller: 'ModalCtrl'
});

var ModalCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
    //Modal controls
    $scope.close = function () {
      console.log("close!") //This will now run
      modalInstance.close();
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need pass `scope` when open modal, like this

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl : 'modal.html',
    scope : $scope
});
```

if you not pass `scope` modal window use `$rootScope.new()`

also you need remove `ng-controller` attribute from template

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modalContainer">
    <div></div>
</script>
```